# count number of rows and get only the last row from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table called `employeexam` which structure and data are like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id | course_id   | employee_id | degree | date
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  1          | 3           | 8      | 2013-01-14
| 2  |  2          | 4           | 15     | 2013-01-14
| 3  |  2          | 4           | 17     | 2013-01-15
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Desired result would be:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | course_id   | employee_id | degree | date        | numOfTakingExams 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  1          | 3           | 8      | 2013-01-14  | 1
| 3  |  2          | 4           | 17     | 2013-01-15  | 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(employeexam.employee_id) as employeeid, 
                employeexam.*, 
                exam.numOfTakingExams 
     FROM employeexam
     JOIN (
            SELECT employee_id , COUNT(employee_id ) as numOfTakingExams 
            FROM employeexam  
            GROUP BY employee_id
          ) exam
     ON exam.employee_id  = employeexam.employee_id 
     ORDER BY employeexam.id DESC
```

This outputs `numOfTakingExams` value correctly, but i can't select only the data of the last time he entered an exam. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.numOfTakingExams
FROM    employeeExam a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  employee_id,
                    MAX(date) max_Date,
                    COUNT(*) numOfTakingExams 
            FROM    employeeExam
            GROUP BY course_ID, employee_id
        ) b ON  a.employee_id = b.employee_id AND
                a.date = b.max_Date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a390f/3)

you can also get the latest record by the maximum `ID` if it is set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, this query below yields the same result from the query above,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.numOfTakingExams
FROM    employeeExam a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  employee_id,
                    MAX(id) max_Date,
                    COUNT(*) numOfTakingExams 
            FROM    employeeExam
            GROUP BY course_ID, employee_id
        ) b ON  a.employee_id = b.employee_id AND
                a.id = b.max_Date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a390f/5)

Comment: It works,  thanks. I edited your [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1948/2) to output also courses that an employee entered for one time.

Comment: @Yasmeen, you can also include `course_ID` on the subquery, [click here SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1948/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.course_id, t1.employee_id, t1.degree, t1.date, t2.numOfTakingExams
FROM
  mployeexam t1
  JOIN (
        SELECT employee_id, MAX(date) date, COUNT(*) numOfTakingExams
        FROM mployeexam
        GROUP BY employee_id
    ) t2
    ON t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id AND t1.date = t2.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a join with itself? In the first you select on the IDs containing the "last exams" and in the second you join the stuff that you need. Something along the lines of:

```
select A.* FROM
employeexam A INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, MAX(DATE)
    FROM EMPLOYEEXAM
    GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_ID
) B
ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID AND
A.DATE = B.DATE
```

Assuming of course the dates per Employee_id are unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ee.*, num_exams
FROM    (
        SELECT  employee_id, COUNT(*) AS num_exams
        FROM    employeexam
        GROUP BY
                employee_id
        ) eed
JOIN    employeeexam ee
ON      ee.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    employeeexam eei
        WHERE   eei.employee_id = eed.employee_id
        ORDER BY
                eei.employee_id DESC, eei.date DESC, eei.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

This will handle the case of multiple exams taken on one date correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.ttl
  FROM employeexam x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT course_id
            , employee_id
            , MAX(date) max_date
            , COUNT(*) ttl 
         FROM employeexam 
        GROUP 
           BY course_id
            ,employee_id
     ) y 
    ON y.course_id = x.course_id 
   AND y.employee_id = x.employee_id 
   AND y.max_date = x.date;
```