# Count number of rows and get only the last row in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, count, aggregation-framework, max

I have a collection of posts as follows:

```json
  {
    "author": "Rothfuss",
    "text": "Name of the Wind",
    "likes": 1007,
    "date": ISODate("2013-03-20T11:30:05Z")
  },
  {
    "author": "Rothfuss",
    "text": "Doors of Stone",
    "likes": 1,
    "date": ISODate("2051-03-20T11:30:05Z")
  }
```

I want to get the count of each author's posts and his/her last post.
There is a SQL answer for the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338146/count-number-of-rows-and-get-only-the-last-row-from-a-table). I try to find its MongoDB alternative.

I ended up this query so far:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$author",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "lastPost": {
        "$max": {
          "_id": "$date",
          "post": "$text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

which seems to work, but its different runs generate different results. It can be tested [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vxT_XEziJuK) in Mongo playground.
I don't understand how to use `$max` to select another property from the document containing the maximum. I am new to MongoDB, so describing the basics is also warmly appreciated.

#### extra question

Is it possible to limit `$sum` to only add posts with `likes` more than 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *its different runs generate different results. 
>
> I don't understand how to use $max to select another property from the document containing the maximum.*

The `$max` does not work in multiple fields, and also it is not effective in that field that having text/string value.

It will select any of the properties from a group of posts, it will different every time.

So the accurate result you can add new stage `$sort` before `$group` stage, to sort by date in descending order, and in the group stage you can select a value by `$first` operator,

```
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      date: { $first: "$date" },
      post: { $first: "$text" }
    }
  }
```

> *Is it possible to limit `$sum` to only add posts with `likes` more than 100?*

There is two meaning of your requirement, I am not sure which is you are asking but let me give both the solutions,

1. If you only don't want to count posts in `count` but you want to get it as the last post's `date` and `text` if it is.

- `$cond` check condition if `likes` is greater than 100 then count 1 otherwise count 0

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      count: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $gt: ["$likes", 100] }, 1, 0]
        }
      },
      date: { $first: "$date" },
      post: { $first: "$text" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wHg24lOLwUs)

2. If you don't want to count and also don't want the last post if it is.

- You can add a `$match` stage at the first stage to check greater than condition, and your final query would be,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { likes: { $gt: 100 } } },
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      date: { $first: "$date" },
      post: { $first: "$text" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3zENJagb-CY)

Comment: @Takis_  OP wants to select recent document by `date` field and `$max` with object properties `date` and `text` is not an accurate way, anyway it is working for you is just a coincident, look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GOYv46WhCsn) with his query, it is not returning recent document by date.

Comment: @turivishal that playground you sended works as it supposed to work,only 1 document,per author passes the filter so it works,it works ok without the filter also,but playground loses the order of fields in documents see [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e_l-y0uUeh7) run an empty aggregation,this is problem of the playground i think.I tested `$max` with 1 million documents,i dont think it was coincident,but if you have an example that `$max` doesn't work on documents send if you can.

Comment: @Takis_ i don't see any problem in playground, it is ok if it is working for you, but it is not a valid way to do this, and just think about how $max operator will know which field has date value from `{ "_id": "$date", "post": "$text" }`? anyway, i don't want to prove anything with you, OP understood perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks ok to me, adding a `$match` stage can filter out the posts if not `likes` > 100. (you can also do it in `$sum`, with `$cond` but there is no need here)

Query

- `$max` accumulator can be used for documents also
  [Here you can see how MongoDB compares documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/)
- mongoplayground has a problem and loses the order of fields in the documents(behaves likes they are are hashmaps when they are not) (test it in your driver also)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gAAZpIJvlmK)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "likes": {
        "$gt": 100
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$author",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "lastPost": {
        "$max": {
          _id: "$date",
          post: "$text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: thank you for your response. `$sum` with `$cond` worked for me, as explained in @turivishal answer. However, I had read how MongoDB compares documents, and had not concluded that there may be a chance factor in it.

Comment: i think `$max` works fine on documents,and you dont need to sort the collection,i tested it now.if someone has a sample data that doesn't work,wil be helpful